# c# get system file cache size

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm trying to get the current system file cache size as shown below. However when I run this code nothing gets returned, can anybody see where I'm going wrong ? 
FYI the link is [GetSystemFileCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool GetSystemFileCacheSize(
        ref IntPtr lpMinimumFileCacheSize,
        ref IntPtr lpMaximumFileCacheSize,
        ref IntPtr lpFlags
        );

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        IntPtr lpMinimumFileCacheSize = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr lpMaximumFileCacheSize = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr lpFlags = IntPtr.Zero;

        bool b = GetSystemFileCacheSize(ref lpMinimumFileCacheSize, ref lpMaximumFileCacheSize, ref lpFlags);
    }
```

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't an example on http://pinvoke.net for that function. (go to the Kernel32.dll sub menu). If you get it working, please add an example to that site (it is a wiki).

Comment: Have you tried calling GetLastWin32Error afterwards to get the error?

Comment: sorry - I'm a complete dope, I had the target platform still set to X86. I feel ashamed now. Once set to any CPU it works fine.

Comment: @Mike - thanks for the suggestion, didn't know about that site. Added example to it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        bool b = GetSystemFileCacheSize(ref lpMinimumFileCacheSize, ref lpMaximumFileCacheSize, ref lpFlags);

        Console.WriteLine(lpMinimumFileCacheSize);
        Console.WriteLine(lpMaximumFileCacheSize);
```

Works fine for me.

Output:

```
1048576
2143289344
```

Windows 7 Pro x32

Comment: a) What numbers (approx) ? and b) 32|64 bits OS?

Comment: OK, I got  0 0 on Win7 x64. And b==false

Comment: @Henk, I have x64 win 7, later i'll try your snippet on it.

Comment: Henk - you need to change your target to either any CPU or x64, works fine then

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet works: (Windows Seven x86)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because of the problem we are encountering relating to [MS KB 976618](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976618) and due to not wanting to run binary code from unknown 3rd parties on production servers I'm being forced in to the c# language.  Because I'm a newb at c# it took me a while but I finally figured out the extra bits around the code snippets people have been posting.  So my full ms visual studio c# console program that compiles and runs is:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool GetSystemFileCacheSize(
        ref IntPtr lpMinimumFileCacheSize,
        ref IntPtr lpMaximumFileCacheSize,
        ref IntPtr lpFlags
        );

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr lpMinimumFileCacheSize = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr lpMaximumFileCacheSize = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr lpFlags = IntPtr.Zero;

        bool b = GetSystemFileCacheSize(ref lpMinimumFileCacheSize, ref lpMaximumFileCacheSize, ref lpFlags);

        Console.WriteLine(b);
        Console.WriteLine(lpMinimumFileCacheSize);
        Console.WriteLine(lpMaximumFileCacheSize);
        Console.WriteLine(lpFlags);
    }
}
```

and on my Windows 7 x64 PC it outputs

```
True
1048576
1099511627776
0
```

and no, that's not our production server.

and then in powershell this is

```
$source = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyTools
{
    public static class cache
    {

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool GetSystemFileCacheSize(
            ref IntPtr lpMinimumFileCacheSize,
            ref IntPtr lpMaximumFileCacheSize,
            ref IntPtr lpFlags
            );

        public static bool Get( ref IntPtr a, ref IntPtr c, ref IntPtr d )
        {
            IntPtr lpMinimumFileCacheSize = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr lpMaximumFileCacheSize = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr lpFlags = IntPtr.Zero;

            bool b = GetSystemFileCacheSize(ref lpMinimumFileCacheSize, ref lpMaximumFileCacheSize, ref lpFlags);

            a = lpMinimumFileCacheSize;
            c = lpMaximumFileCacheSize;
            d = lpFlags;
            return b;
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -Language CSharp

# Init variables
$SFCMin = 0
$SFCMax = 0
$SFCFlags = 0
$b = [MyTools.cache]::Get( [ref]$SFCMin, [ref]$SFCMax, [ref]$SFCFlags )

#typecast values so we can do some math with them
$SFCMin = [long]$SFCMin
$SFCMax = [long]$SFCMax
$SFCFlags = [long]$SFCFlags

write-output "Return values from GetSystemFileCacheSize are: "
write-output "Function Result : $b"
write-output "            Min : $SFCMin"
write-output ("            Max : $SFCMax ( " + $SFCMax / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 + " GiB )")
write-output "          Flags : $SFCFlags"
```

Next step: SetSystemFileCacheSize, I've written a powershell script for this and put it on https://serverfault.com/questions/325277/windows-server-2008-r2-metafile-ram-usage/527466#527466